# Comparing ntext values without casting or converting

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I want to compare ntext values  without casting to nvarchar. Is there any way to do it?
Casting to nvarchar works for me but there is a performance issue.

Thanks in advance

Comment: compare with what? and is the performance causing some bottlneck in your application?

Comment: I am comparing a ntext value with another ntext value. I got an error "ntext values are incomparable with the operator". Apparently comparison operators do not work on ntext/text values.

Comment: It is taking time to give the final result. If i compare more than two tables it would take even more time to give the result.

Comment: com.CreateCommand=select tb1.Field1,tb1.Field2,tb2.Field2,tb1.Field3 from [Server].[database][schema].[table] as tb1, [Server].[database][schema].[table] as tb2 where ((tb1.Field2 <> tb2.Field2)OR( cast(tb1.Field3 as nvarchar(100)) <> cast(tb2.Field3 as nvarchar(100)))and (tb1.Field1=tb2.Field1)";

Comment: I am comparing two table from two databases on two servers...and both the tables have same fields and in my actual code i am casting some 30 fields for both tables

Comment: How about changing the data type of the column to nvarchar(max)?. Not sure that it will help you with performance even if you can skip the cast but it is worth a try.

Comment: I cannot change anything in the client database :(

Comment: But you could setup a test to see if the cast really is an issue for you.

Comment: It is an issue because i am using the same query for access databases and there is no casting involved. it is only in SQL that i am facing the problem

Comment: @MikaelEriksson: I am sorry . I just checked with my access databases ...the field types are different from the field types in the SQL database. I'll set up a test to check if  casting is the real problem. Thanks

Comment: @MikaelEriksson: i tried..no luck..casting seems to the problem